# change the current clicked marker Icon using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-markers

I am using leaflet plugin to show the marker. When I click on the current marker the icon should change the current marker only.

Again when I click on another marker change that marker to new icon and keep all other marker icon original.

Like I have 2 marker Icon 
 1- original Icon which I am setting when showing the marker on map
 2- new marker - I want this marker icon should be set when click on marker.Only current Marker Icon should be changed and keep all other Icon Original Icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a marker layer? If yes you could first create a new icon

```
var customIcon = L.Icon.extend({
    options: {
        iconSize: [40.4, 44],
        iconAnchor: [20, 43],
        popupAnchor: [0, -51]
    }
});

var myCustomIcon = new CustomIcon({ iconUrl: '../images/marker.png' });
```

After that you should get clicked marker's index inside the Layer and update the icon like this:

```
markersLayer[markersIndex].setIcon(myCustomIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.
When you click the `marker1`, its icon will change to the one you set.

```
let marker1 = L.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], { icon: greenIcon }).on('click', ()=>{
                marker1.setIcon(redIcon)
              }).addTo(map)
```